# Maximum Speed in Google Location Services for Android

Tags: android, location

I am writing an app that needs to be able to measure speeds and I am using Google location services for Android to get speeds.  It works fine up to around 300KPH and then the speed simply comes back as 0.  I tested this by using the app on a recent flight I was on.

Does anyone have any idea if there is some kind of limit in place?

Comment: Show us some code ;)

Comment: Can you provide more details of what API/method calls you are executing?

Comment: Pretty simple really.  I'm using `speed.setText("Spd: "+ Math.round(location.getSpeed()*3.6));` to display the speed where location comes from the onLocationChanged method of the LocationListener.

Comment: So I guess no one has come across this before?  I seem to recall reading something once that said that there was some kind of speed limit placed on consumer oriented GPS capable devices to prevent them from being used for evil purposes.  Probably just an urban legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I ended up creating my own speedometer using a handler that calculates the speed based on distance traveled between calls to the function.  It seems pretty accurate, now I just need to get on a plane to see if it works at high speed.